# Fit undirected Bayesian Network with bnlearn

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, undirected-graph, bnlearn

I learnt Bayesian Network (BN) structures with the `bnlearn` package in R. However, for some of my BN, I have undirected edges.

Thus, when I want to fit the BN (*i.e.* learn the Conditional Probability Tables = CPT), I obtain this error message telling me that it is not possible to learn CPT:

```
Error in bn.fit(struct_list[[i]][[ii]], data = dbnBnlearn_general %>% ... : the graph is only partially directed.
```

So my question is: is there a way to force the structure to be directed (I tried the `undirected` argument of the structure learning algorithm but there are still undirected edges)?

Cheers

Comment: `?bnlearn::cextend` (or you could use a score based alg to learn the structure)

Comment: I tried to use it but this time I have: `Error in cextend(struct_list[[3]][[1]]) : 
  no consistent extension of struct_list[[3]][[1]] is possible.`

Comment: see `?cextend` ; you can force it to return a partially directed graph with the `strict` parameter. Maybe then inspect the graph to see why it cannot be extended further? Does adding `debug=TRUE` give any useful info? This question then might be a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com -- but an example would be needed.

Comment: ps it may not be possible to extend as it adding an additional edge may introduce new v-structures or cycles.

Comment: Yes, I think it is just not possible to introduce a new v-structure. Thx a lot for your help